# Problem to write on txt file on specific line

Tags: java, javafx, text-files

**Student.txt**

```
1,Giannis,Oreos,Man
2,Maria,Karra,Woman
3,Maria,Oaka,Woman
```

After run my code I take this:

**Student.txt**

```
1,Giannis,Oreos,Man
2,Maria,Karra,Woman
3,Maria,Oaka,Woman,2,3,1,3,4,6
```

But I want, if I search for `ID=2` go to 2nd line and put the numbers, like that:

**Student.txt**

```
1,Giannis,Oreos,Man
2,Maria,Karra,Woman,2,3,1,3,4,6
3,Maria,Oaka,Woman
```

**Code:**

```
@FXML 
TextField ID1,glossa,math,fis,xim,prog,gym;

@FXML
public void UseAddLesson() throws IOException{
    Scanner x = new Scanner("src/inware/students.txt");

    FileWriter fW = new FileWriter("src/inware/students.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(fW);

    boolean found= false;

    while(!found){
        String line = x.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(ID1.getText())){
            bW.write(","+glossa.getText()+",");
            bW.write(math.getText()+",");
            bW.write(fis.getText()+",");
            bW.write(xim.getText()+",");
            bW.write(prog.getText()+",");
            bW.write(gym.getText());
            System.out.println(line);
            found= true;
        }
    }
    bW.close();
    fW.close();
    x.close();
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `ID1.getText()` equals 2 ?

Comment: yes,because i take the 2nd txt output, i have put textbox so i can write ID number e.g. 2

Comment: okay , what shows this line `System.out.println(line);` ?

Comment: for e.g ID=2, Print Ourput: 2,Maria,Karra,Woman and i take the 2rd txt output

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not attempt to read/write to the same file at the same time. You also cannot append/overwrite the structure of a text file requires all the text following the inserting point to be written at a different position.

I recommend creating a temporary file and replacing the old file with the new one you're done:

```
@FXML
public void UseAddLesson() throws IOException{
    String searchText = ID1.getText();
    Path p = Paths.get("src", "inware", "students.txt");
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(p.getParent(), "studentsTemp", ".txt");
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
            BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile)) {
        String line;

        // copy everything until the id is found
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            writer.write(line);
            if (line.contains(searchText)) {
                writer.write(","+glossa.getText()+",");
                writer.write(math.getText()+",");
                writer.write(fis.getText()+",");
                writer.write(xim.getText()+",");
                writer.write(prog.getText()+",");
                writer.write(gym.getText());
                break;
            }
            writer.newLine();
        }

        // copy remaining lines
        if (line != null) {
            writer.newLine();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
    }

    // copy new file & delete temporary file
    Files.copy(tempFile, p, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.delete(tempFile);
}
```

**Note:** If you distribute the app, probably the `src` directory will become unavailable.

Comment: I have try the given code, and it work perfectly. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: How should i change the `if (line.contains(searchText))` so i can delete lines?